# ASP.NET C# application SSO with SAML 2.0 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I have a custom .NET CRM system (System A, IDP) with a forms based authentication that I want to have SSO with a SAML 2.0 API (System B, SP) we purchased. The user and password are stored in the SQL database and upon successful login to System A I want to be able to post an assertion to System B with enough data to complete the SSO process. I am either not finding a lot on this subject or I am searching using the wrong keywords so I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction. I am looking for a good tutorial or place to start on how to generate a SAML 2.0 assertion from my System A.

Comment: Try: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-C

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API in the [Kentor.AuthServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) SAML2 library to do that.

```
var response = new Saml2Response(
            new EntityId(systemAUrl),
            CertificateHelper.SigningCertificate,
            new Uri(AssertionConsumerServiceUrl),
            null, null, claimsIdentity);

var bindingResult = Saml2Binding.Get(model.AssertionModel.ResponseBinding).Bind(response)

// If this is an MVC action you can convert the bindingResult to
// an ActionResult using the ToActionResult() extension from the
// Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc package.
return bindingResult.ToActionResult();

// If you're using web forms, you can use the Apply() extension
// method from the Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule package. Apply
// calls Response.End() internally.
bindingResult.Apply(new HttpResponseWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Response));
```

The above code is a condensed version of what's done in the stub idp, see https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L66 for the full version.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kentor.AuthServices.*

Comment: I see this is using MVC. How would your solution work in a webforms App?

Comment: @ChrisLombardi Updated example code with web forms example.

Answer (score -3):

If you're after a commercial offering, please take a look at [our SAML v2.0 class library](http://www.componentspace.com/SAMLv20.aspx).

We include an ExampleIdentityProvider WebForms ASP.NET example project that demonstrates how to call into our API to construct a SAML assertion wrapped in a SAML response and send it to the service provider.